# web developer tools linux

Tags: linux

I started using Linux for PHP web development. What is a helpful toolset to use for web development (mostly PHP) available for the Linux platform. My Current IDE is netbeans and I am happy with it.

Comment: Is this your first foray into linux?

Answer (score 3):

In no particular order, my perfect environment consists of:

- [vim](http://www.vim.org/) - text editing
- [git](http://git-scm.com/) - version control
- [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) - terminal management

This is all you really need to build a great app in any language, for that matter (baseline). Every language has its specifics, but the above will more than get you started.

Comment: I agree, this is the exact toolset I use myself. However, I wouldn't push any of these tools onto anybody ;)

Answer (score 3):

> The PDT project provides a PHP
>   Development Tools framework for the
>   Eclipse platform. This project
>   encompasses all development components
>   necessary to develop PHP and
>   facilitate extensibility. It leverages
>   the existing Web Tools Platform (WTP)
>   and Dynamic Languages Toolkit (DLTK)
>   in providing developers with PHP
>   capabilities.

You can have a try for eclipse.

http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/

Answer (score 1):

Another one not mentioned in this thread (suitable for PHP and a lot of other dynamic languages):

[Komodo Edit (free version of the Komodo IDE)](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/)

Answer (score 0):

I really like using [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org) and SqlSquirrel. Both of these tools are written in Java and they are cross platform compatible. Also an odd note about SqlSquirrel: It uses the Netbeans editor. Also, if you like there are many tutorials and articles on using PHP with Netbeans on their site. Overall, go with the toolset that you like the most. There isn't a single toolset that works with everyone, and for all problems.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Eclipse PDT](http://eclipse.org/pdt/), and it can be used both on Windows *(which I use at work)* and on Linux *(which I use at home)*.

Features are quite the same as netbeans, I'd say ; especially, you've got nice stuff like graphical debugging, when used with [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/).

I'd say that, these days, when it comes to a modern full-IDE for PHP, that works on Linux, and is free, there are two choices : netbeans and Eclipse PDT. Which one you prefer is generally a matter of taste, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy with NetBeans, stick to that as you IDE. Learn to use Vim or emacs just for common knowledge. Use version control, Subversion and git are good choices.

The power of linux is in the command line. Whatever you do outside the IDE, learn to do it with command line. After a while you'll be comfortable with it and you'll discover that there's bunch of stuff you never want to do with GUIs anymore :)